# How to override a plugin from the parent in pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven

My pom.xml has this in it:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I believe this parent provides the **maven-surefire-plugin**. However, I need to change the configuration of the **maven-surefire-plugin** so that log4j logs are not printed to the console during tests. I should be able to do it by changing the pom.xml, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935715/disabling-log4j-logs-during-maven-test-phase).

However, I have tried adding the following to my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <log4j.configuration>file:src/test/resources/log4j-silent.properties</log4j.configuration>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But logs are still being printed to the screen. I suspect it's because I'm not properly overriding the **maven-surefire-plugin** that **spring-boot-starter-parent** provides.

Comment: Hum your override seems correct, although I would not specify any version number for that plugin (but inherit what is defined in a parent). Are you 100% sure your log4j file is correct? And forkMode is not on the documentation of the latest version, you should use forkCount and reuseFork: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: @S.Piller I am sure my log4j file is correct.

Comment: so the best I can tell is that the path you are using is invalid. try using an absolute path, maybe file://${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/log4j-silent.properties. Look closely at the output to see if log4j is complaining and fallbacking to a default configuration.