# External set logging level during mvn tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, logging, verify

I've faced the following problem. Application is build using CI tool and logging level is set internally to INFO. However during tests, the quantity of the logs' weight is more then 15 mb and it's causing error of CI runner.

Is there any way to avoid logging during verify execution ?
I've tried to run with -q flag, but its working only for the logs generated by directly by mvn, not including logs level from java and spring.

There is a dump solution to set logging level to error and then manually after verify stage change it to INFO, but I want to avoid that kind of hacky solution.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Thanks for answers. I've handled this with adding additional log config file in test/resources in each module + CI is starting verify's stage with -q flag.

Comment: maybe forking the test and loading another config file. some info could help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161754/how-to-override-a-plugin-from-the-parent-in-pom-xml#comment81273743_47161754 but as far as I can tell, there is no really good reason in doing this.

Comment: Really a problem having 15 mb of logs? And this causes an error in your CI ?You can of course add an approriate configuration file for the test in `src/test/resources`?

Comment: What plugin is generating so much logs? You can provide your pom.xml config so we can identify how to recude log output.

Comment: @khmarbaise that would prevent the developer from seeing the logs, too. :) but I agree that a CI tool that fails to load 15Mb of logs should be thrown away.

Comment: Just redirect the logs into a file into `target/` ...